# Creating an ImageBrush from a WebRequest stream

Tags: c#, wpf, stream, imagebrush

I am having difficulties creating my `ImageBrush` from a `Stream`. The following code is used to fill a WPF `Rectangle` using an `ImageBrush`:

```
        ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
        imgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("\\image.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Rectangle1.Fill = imgBrush;
```

What I want to do is call a `WebRequest` and obtain a `Stream`. Then I want to fill my rectangle using the `Stream` image. Here is the code:

```
        ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(iconurl);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
        imgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(s);  // Here is the problem
        Rectangle1.Fill = imgBrush;
```

The problem is that I do not know how to set my `imgBrush.ImageSource` using `response.GetResponseStream()`. How can I consume a `Stream` in my `ImageBrush`?

Answer (score 0):

The [`BitmapImage` constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) don't have an overload taking a `Stream` as parameter.
To use the response stream, you should use the parameterless constructor and set the [`StreamSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

It would look like this:

```
// Get the stream for the image
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(iconurl);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();

// Load the stream into the image
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.StreamSource = s;

// Apply image as source
ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
imgBrush.ImageSource = image;

// Fill the rectangle
Rectangle1.Fill = imgBrush;
```